# Django Model-Register

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My users upload sensor measurements to a django-backend. Before the upload, they post some foreignkey meta data via rest-calls, like Sensorposition and Sensorname from the models

```
class Sensorname(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Sensorposition(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Sometimes they want to upload a compressed file that contains measurements from multiple different sensors and they would like to post a Sensor-Registry for them that contains the name, positions and a description.pdf for each of the measured sensors:

```
Sensor-Registry-Name
Sensor1name Sensor1positions Sensor1description.pdf
Sensor2name Sensor2positions Sensor2description.pdf
...
```

I came up with the solution to have a Sensor class

```
class Sensor(models.Model):
    sensorname= models.ForeignKey(Sensorname)
    sensorpositions = models.ManyToManyField('Sensorposition')
    description_pdf =  models.FileField(...)
```

which then can be added to a SensorRegistry that looks like this

```
class SensorRegistry(models.Model):
    registryname=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sensors = models.ManyToManyField('Sensor')
```

This solution works okayish, however, if the same sensor is used at a different position, e.g. ["front"] instead of ["middle", "left"], the users first have to create a new Sensor with the same Sensorname and Sensordescription but with a different position.

Edit : So basically I want to remove the sensorposition from the Sensor class and allow to register as many Sensor instances as desired for a given SensorRegistry, but I also want to register a Sensorposition for each Sensor in the Registry respectively

Comment: Why exactly do they have to create new sensors when the position changes? From your Sensor model, it can have as many positions as possible so they can reuse the sensor with different positions

Comment: If the measurement contains Sensorname "A" twice, once with Position "front" and once with Position "back", the registry has to have two entries, 
1) Sensor1name, front, sensor1.pdf
2) Sensor1name, back, sensor1.pdf

Comment: You have sensorposition as a many-to-many field. Which means that many sensorpositions can be linked with one sensor. You can have Sensor1name, [front, back], sensor1.pdf